# insert word under cursor in projectile search

Tags: key-bindings, helm, spacemacs

when typing in some `projectile` filter string for instance (eg `SPC p f`) in `spacemacs`, I often would like to reuse the word under the cursor.

I know about `C-y` to paste. Which is the one to insert the word under the cursor? I stumbled on `C-w` but it's not that. And why does `C-w` does by the way??

(btw if there is something more `spacemacs`-y I'm interested)

Comment: @Drew The question title is completely unclear to me. But I understand what he's asking from the body: he wants to insert the word at the point when using `projectile-find-file`.

Comment: I think it's called the minibuffer. Unfortunately I'm not too familiar with the correct emacs terminology (vim convert using spacemacs).

Comment: the reason for the title is because I had found about `C-w` and didn't understand its behaviour. I thought it stopped at some separator on left and right before hitting the spaces. I now think that it goes from cursor to space. I want the whole word under the cursor, from the space (or bracked) before to the space (or dot, or bracket) after.

Comment: The question is clearer after the edit to remove mention of `C-s` etc. Thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Helm (which I believe is the default in Spacemacs), you can insert the word at the point with `M-n` or `C-w`.

From the [Helm Wiki](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/wiki#yanking-text):

> To yank the symbol at point from `helm-current-buffer` (i.e. buffer where a helm command originated):
>
> `M-n`
>
> Alternatively, customize `helm-yank-symbol-first` to enable
>
> `C-w`
>
> to always yank the whole symbol on first invocation.

Comment: Ok, `M-n` is what I want. `C-w` inserts from the cursor to the end of the word. `M-n` inserts the whole word. HOWEVER, `M-n` is a pain to reach on the keyboard... Is there any way I could remap `M-n` to another key or change the `C-w` behaviour to be more like `M-n`?

Comment: @EmmanuelTouzery While in Helm, if I do `C-h c M-n`, I can see that the key is mapped to the function `next-history-element`. So you can do `(define-key helm-map (kbd "C-w") 'next-history-element)` to assign `C-w` to the same function as `M-n`.

Comment: thanks, I tried it but it didn't work. I get `symbol's value as variable is void: helm-map`. Otherwise I checked and what I am in is called `help projectile`.

Comment: Most likely you're getting the "`helm-map` is void" error because you're making the assignment before launching Helm and thereby autoloading the rest of the Helm package.  You should probably do `(with-eval-after-load 'helm (define-key ...))` instead, which delays the binding until everything has been properly loaded.

Comment: That helm wiki section is outdated: `helm-yank-symbol-first` doesn't exist any more.

Comment: I have updated the helm wiki by removing the outdated info.

Comment: looks like `M-n` works for me by chance, the doc says `If you type M-n in the minibuffer when there are no later entries in the minibuffer history (e.g., if you haven’t previously typed M-p), Emacs tries fetching from a list of default arguments: values that you are likely to enter. You can think of this as moving through the “future history” list.` -- so it's a heuristic and behaviour may change in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Below is some commands that operate text between current buffer and minibuffer in helm:

- <kbd>C-w</kbd> (`helm-yank-text-at-point`) Append the next word at point into minibuffer, like `isearch`'s <kbd>C-w</kbd>
- <kbd>M-n</kbd> (`next-history-element`) Move through the “future history” list (see manual [Minibuffer History](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Minibuffer-History.html), the first element of it is the symbol at point in the beginning)
- <kbd>C-c C-y</kbd> (`helm-yank-selection`) Set minibuffer contents to helm selection
- <kbd>C-c C-k</kbd> (`helm-kill-selection-and-quit`) Save helm selection to kill-ring and quit helm
- <kbd>C-c C-i</kbd> (`helm-copy-to-buffer`) Insert helm selection into the current buffer

---

If you want <kbd>C-w</kbd> to insert from the beginning of word, not the cursor's position, you can try the following hack:

```el
(defun helm-yank-text-at-point--move-to-beginning (orig-func &rest args)
  "Initialize `helm-yank-point' to the beginning of word at point."
  (unless helm-yank-point
    (setq helm-yank-point
          (with-helm-current-buffer
            (save-excursion
              (let ((fwd-fn (or helm-yank-text-at-point-function #'forward-word)))
                (funcall fwd-fn -1))
              (point)))))
  (apply orig-func args))

(advice-add 'helm-yank-text-at-point :around
            #'helm-yank-text-at-point--move-to-beginning)
```

Comment: otherwise for me `C-w` doesn't insert the word, but from the cursor the end of the word. That's why I resorted to that shortcut remap. I would prefer if I could say to `C-w`, give me the full word, not only from cursor to end of word.

Comment: well now I noticed that isearch's `C-w` does the same as the helm's default of inserting cursor-to-end-of-word. Can that be changed too?

Comment: found it here, to get `C-w` to insert the whole word! http://emacswiki.org/emacs/SearchAtPoint#toc6

Comment: @EmmanuelTouzery The added answer should do what you need on helm's `C-w`, but it looks complex since it changes some helm internal variable, besides it may no work in the future.

Comment: Ok thank you. Then I'll stick with the `M-n` alias for now and keep this in mind (also one day to review when I want to improve my emacs lisp skills).

Answer (score 1):

There is `SPC *` command that will do `SPC / [word_under_the_cursor]`.
`SPC /` is a search project command.

Edit: added `SPC /` explanation

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  Please expand on your answer to give more details about what the commands are doing.

Comment: i think the answer is clear, but it's spacemacs/doom emacs specific